# what is the meaning of ImageView.ScaleType="MATRIX" : Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I know about the `matrix`, its structure and working about image view's scale-type. but,

1. I can't find the exact meaning of `ImageView.ScaleType="MATRIX"`. By declaring this, what exactly happens while drawing the image view.
2. When can I use `ImageView.ScaleType="MATRIX"` ?
3. How does it differ from `FIT_END` & `FIT_START`

I googled about it and also referred the [official link](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) but was not able to find the exact answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. `ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX` lets you use a `Matrix` to scale the image. You can set the Matrix using `ImageView.setImageMatrix(matrix)`. So by declaring the **scaleType** to **MATRIX** you are saying that you want to use an explicit Matrix to do that.
2. You can use `imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX)` whenever you want to customize the way the your image scales, rotates, etc. at your desire.
3. `FIT_END` and `FIT_START` are default types of scale. So, if you use `FIT_END` for instance, your image will maintain the original aspect ratio and it will align the result of the right and bottom edges of your image view. So basically, the difference is that `FIT_END` and `FIT_START` are "presets" while with `MATRIX` you declare that you want to use your own matrix to scale.

Read [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) for more info

Answer (score 4):

As per my understanding, Use below details for each ImageView's ScaleType attributes

**center**

Displays the image centered in the view with no scaling.

**centerCrop**

Scales the image such that both the x and y dimensions are greater than or equal to the view, while maintaining the image aspect ratio; crops any part of the image that exceeds the size of the view; centers the image in the view.

**centerInside**

Scales the image to fit inside the view, while maintaining the image aspect ratio. If the image is already smaller than the view, then this is the same as center.

**fitCenter**

Scales the image to fit inside the view, while maintaining the image aspect ratio. At least one axis will exactly match the view, and the result is centered inside the view.

**fitStart**

Same as fitCenter but aligned to the top left of the view.

**fitEnd**

Same as fitCenter but aligned to the bottom right of the view.

**fitXY**

Scales the x and y dimensions to exactly match the view size; does not maintain the image aspect ratio.

**matrix**

Scales the image using a supplied Matrix class. The matrix can be supplied using the setImageMatrix method. A Matrix class can be used to apply transformations such as rotations to an image.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation you linked to provides the answer you are looking for.

> Scale using the image matrix when drawing. The image matrix can be set using [`setImageMatrix(Matrix)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageMatrix(android.graphics.Matrix)). From XML, use this syntax: `android:scaleType="matrix"`

Although you mentioned that you already know what a `Matrix` is in the context of graphics, I will explain briefly for the sake of other users who come across this question- A matrix can be used to manipulate the canvas when drawing graphics. In the case of an `ImageView`'s matrix, you can use it to translate, flip, rotate, or otherwise move the image around on the screen.

> when i can use ImageView.ScaleType="MATRIX"

You can use it whenever you want with an `ImageView`. You can call [`setScaleType()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setScaleType(android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType)) in your Java code to use a matrix scale type or you can add the `android:scaleType="matrix"` attribute in your layout XML.

> how it differs from FIT_END & FIT_START

[`FIT_END`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.ScaleToFit.html#END) and [`FIT_START`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.ScaleToFit.html#START) both actually use a `Matrix` to scale your image. Both maintain the original aspect ratio and fit the image entirely within the view, but just align the result differently. End will align the scaled image to the end of the `ImageView`, whereas start will align the scaled image to the start of the `ImageView`

Answer (score 2):

### ScaleType="MATRIX"

A `Matrix` is constructed and scaled based on the user’s pinch gesture scale factor and then the `ImageView` set based on this scaled Matrix.
Please visit here [Android ImageView ScaleType](http://milkmidi.blogspot.in/2011/09/android-imageview-scaletype.html)

Check the [Effect](http://etcodehome.blogspot.in/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html).And https://guides.codepath.com/android/Working-with-the-ImageView

Comment: I would strongly recommend the last link to anyone who asks anything about `scaleType`. There's the real answer to this kind of questions.