# expand/collapse Animation Android half view

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I would like to expand/collapse an ImageView but start from 50% picture to expand at 100%, collapse to 50% not under.

I already took a look at some popular questions and answers on SO but I didn't find how to manage only half. I also want to modify on the height of view, not the width.

What I tried :

```
public static void expand(final View v) {
    v.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final int targtetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    v.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation a = new Animation()
    {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                    ? ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    : (int)(targtetHeight * interpolatedTime);
            v.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    a.setDuration((int)(targtetHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    v.startAnimation(a);
}

public static void collapse(final View v) {
    final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    Animation a = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            if (interpolatedTime == 1) {
                v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - (int) (initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    a.setDuration((int) (initialHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    v.startAnimation(a);
}
```

as I said it's not what I want because it make disappeared totally and it change the width.

I also tried this snippet but there is no animation :

```
mImageDrawable = (ClipDrawable) pic.getDrawable();
mImageDrawable.setLevel(5000);//use set level to expand or collapse manually but no animation.
```

clip:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<clip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:clipOrientation="vertical"
    android:drawable="@drawable/test_pic"
    android:gravity="top" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Transition API which is available in support package (androidx). Just call `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition` then change height of view. `TransitionManager` will handle this changes and it will provide transition which will change imageView with animation.

[image]

`scaleType` of `ImageView` here is `centerCrop` thats why image scales when collapse and expand. Unfortunetly there is no "fill width and crop bottom" scaleType, so if you need it I think it can be done throught [scaleType = matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31788011/what-is-the-meaning-of-imageview-scaletype-matrix-android)  .

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.transition.TransitionManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private ImageView image;
  private ViewGroup parent;
  boolean collapse = true;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    image = findViewById(R.id.image);
    parent = findViewById(R.id.parent);

    findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(view -> {
        collapse = !collapse;
        collapse();
    });
  }

  private void collapse() {
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(parent);
    //change layout params
    int height = image.getHeight();
    LayoutParams layoutParams = image.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height = !collapse ? height / 2 : height * 2;
    image.requestLayout();
  }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:text="start"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/qwe" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="random text"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE:**

There is `beginDelayedTransition(ViewGroup, Transtion)` method. `beginDelayedTransition(ViewGroup)` by default use `AutoTransition` as transition. 
So if you need handle start/end of transition you can do it like this:

```
    AutoTransition transition = new AutoTransition();
    transition.addListener(new TransitionListenerAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void onTransitionStart(@NonNull Transition transition) {
            //TODO
        }
        @Override
        public void onTransitionEnd(@NonNull Transition transition) {
            //TODO 
        }
    });
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(parent, transition);
```

Comment: I also wanted this scale effect! So your code works as well and this is exactly what I wanted! :)

Comment: I have another question related to this transition. How can I know when the animation/transition is finished? I need to do stuff as soon as the transition/animation is finished.

Comment: working like a charm ! Thanks for updating your answer so quickly !